# Trouble printing 5 elements of a double array per line in C

Tags: c, arrays, formatting, printf, output

I've been working on an assignment for school, basically we're creating 2 arrays of random doubles, then sorting them using 3 different algorithms and printing the results. The output needs to be printed with 5 elements per line.

I've got this code:

```
    //print sorted arrayB
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf ("%.1lf  ", arrayB[i]);
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0)
    {
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

where all variables are defined before the sort, and my output looks like this every time:

```
1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0
7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0 11.0
12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0
17.0 18.0 19.0 20.0 21.0
etc...
```

I don't understand why it's printing 6 elements in the top row, and 5 in all the rest. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider (a) debugging this in a debugger, and short of that (b) instrumenting this by putting a few additional printf statements in to demonstrate the values of those if() conditions and how they may differ from your assumptions of what they actually are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `\n` condition as below -

```
if ((i+1) % 5 == 0)
    {
        printf ("\n");
    }
```

`i % 5` will cause newlines after indices `5,10,15..`. This is your case where you have 6 at index 5, 11 at index 10..
Rather you need to break at `4,9,14..`. which are all covered by `(i+1)`.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I ended up doing after reading the first comment! c:

Comment: @H.Johnson Note that if you use this solution, you can leave out the `&& i > 0` part, because `i + 1` will *never* be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the evaluation by hand for your conditional:

```
if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0)

i  result
0  false
1  false
2  false
3  false
4  false
5  true
6  false
```

Now we can see that it is false 5 times, then true, which makes it print a newline, but only after you printed the number!

So you need to rearrange your logic slightly, but the conditional is correct.

Comment: Thanks, seeing it laid out like that got me to i+1 for the conditional. Works perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

The point is in the `&& i > 0` part of the `if` statement. If you'd remove it, this would be the output:

```
1.0
2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0
7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0 11.0
12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0
17.0 18.0 19.0 20.0 21.0
etc...
```

By excluding zero, you have prevented printing the newline after the first number, see?

The solution is to move the `i` index by one, like this:

```
if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
{
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Now you don't even need the `&& i > 0` part, because `i + 1` will never be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 to i(therefore the condition i > 0, becomes unnecessary), which will solve. This occurs because in the condition imposed by you, for the first line break (\ n) to occur, it will have to go from 0 to 5, and to do so you will have to repeat the loop 6 times, so on the first line it showed 6 numbers , instead of 5

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 25

int main() {
 int i, arrayB[SIZE] = {0};
 for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
     printf ("%.1lf  ", arrayB[i]);
     if ((i+1) % 5 == 0)
     {
         printf ("\n");
     }
 }
return 0;
}
```